# RDP through ICMP

Tags: rdp, icmp

I have got a VM in Google Compute Engine. And I want to use this VM using RDP. I have enabled the firewall settings to accept RDP(TCP:3389). This works fine when I connect to it using a LAN connection. But when I try to connect to this VM using an ICMP connection(ICMP tunneling software), it shows an error that couldn't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

   1. Remote access to server is not enabled.
   2. The remote computer is turned on.
   3. The remote computer is not available on the network.

But my current configuration works fine when I connect over a LAN. I want to use RDP using an ICMP tunnel. Is there a way to use RDP using ICMP?

Ping also works when trying to connect through ICMP.